# Lambda An error occurred while attempting to execute your code

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am using AWS Lambda toolkit for C#. When I am publishing AWS Lambda directly it is working fine on AWS. But when I am trying to make a zip file by using publish and then making the zip of all DLL under bin\Release\netcoreapp1.0. and trying to run.

Then it is giving an error:

```
{
  "errorType": "LambdaException",
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred while attempting to execute your code."
}
```

In configuration Handler name is correct.

What can be the issue?

Comment: are you sure you are zipping everything the app needs?

Comment: I am only zipping all DLL's and JSON file under bin\Release\netcoreapp1.0. There is one more folder generating PublishOutput in this folder it is generating "Sample.Lambda.nupkg" file. I am not adding this to development package. However I checked it with this also but still I am getting the same error. I am adding "Sample.Lambda.deps.json", "Sample.Lambda.dll" ,"Sample.Lambda.pbd", "Sample.pdb." Can you please share with me the procedure. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: Don't zip anything, run dotnet lambda publish from your folder and it will create the ZIP for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried packing the zip using the `dotnet cli command`?

Try this in your project folder: `dotnet lambda package -o .\lambda.zip`

It should create a `lambda.zip` file which you can try to upload.